# Magnetic field produced in an inductor by DC sources

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits

We have an ideal inductor with the dc source in figure A.

When switch is closed we get equal and opposite voltage across the inductor against the source voltage and a constant rate of rise of current given by di/dt = V/L. This constant rate of rise/change in current will also produce the rising magnetic field (shown in green colour).

Suppose some how we reverse the battery instantly, shown in figure B. That reversed battery will cause the reversed electric and magnetic field.

My question is that we have two electric and magnetic fields now. One is caused by the current from the battery and the other ones when we reverse the battery. How will these two interact ? Will they cancel out each other ? Will they add with each other ? Or anything else will happen ?

[image]

Comment: What do *you* think will happen and why? What is the problem you have with that prediction?

Comment: i need to know whether the two magnetic fields will cancel out eachother or will add up?

Comment: Magnetic field is due to and is proportional to electric current flowing through the inductor. What other magnetic field do you think is there?

Comment: the battery voltage we have its an electric field within the wire and when we connect the battery electric field is established and it then establish magnetic field.

Comment: In situations where EM radiation is negligible, electric field or its change *does not* establish any magnetic field, magnetic field is due to electric current only. The battery starts and maintains Coulomb electric field in the region of the circuit, where the lines of force of this electric field run from + to - terminal of the battery. This is reversed by the polarity change and then the battery acts against the established current to decrease it. But the value of current and its direction do not change immediately after the switch. The same is true for magnetic field.

Comment: i have come to read that battery causes conservative field while the induced fields are non conservative. can you tell what will be their combination look like ?

Comment: That is a broad question that is hard to answer in a comment. Maybe post a new question.

Comment: you can edit your answer if you know that. i shall be grateful.